# Inheriting configuration from parent app in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have an application that is constructed as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(), {
    '/api': api.create_app()
})

app.config['DATABASE'] = db
```

I want to access the same database in both the `frontend` and `api` apps, but when I run something like `current_app.config['DATABASE']` in Blueprints registered to `api`, that raises `KeyError: 'DATABASE'`. Is it possible to inherit configurations so that tests, etc. need only modify the top-level abstraction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your `create_app` methods on `frontend` and `api` to take a configuration dictionary and use [`flask.Config`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Config) to create a configuration with all the properties of `app.config` (loadable from environmental variables, etc.):

```
from flask import Config
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddlware

config = Config()
config.from_envvar("YOUR_PROGRAM_CONFIG")

app = DispatcherMiddlware(frontend.create_app(config), {
    '/api': api.create_app(config)
})
```

Then you can merge the provided config with each of your app's configurations:

```
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(config)

    # Potentially, load another config
    app.config.from_envvar("YOUR_PROGRAM_CONFIG_FRONTEND", silent=True)

    return app
```

Note that there is no need to create an app to route to other apps - the [dispatcher middleware](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/middlewares/#werkzeug.wsgi.DispatcherMiddleware) can already do that for you.

Also note that if you are already using blueprints it may make more sense to simply ship the blueprints and compose them on a single application, rather than using dispatcher middleware (depending, of course on how complex your apps are).